# ASP.NET Core EventLog Not Registering

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've been trying to add an EventLog Provider for logging in my ASP.NET Application. I was able to add it to the 'Application' source, but there's a lot of information in that log and I'd like for it to be under it's own source. I've actually gotten 3 logs to be written to it's own source, but I have no idea how or why. This is what my code looks like right now:

```
CreateWebHostBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging( logging =>
            {


                logging.AddEventLog(
                    new Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.EventLogSettings
                    {
                        SourceName = "MySweetApp",
                        MachineName = ".",
                        LogName = "MySweetApp",
                        Filter = (category, level) =>
                        {
                            if (category.EndsWith("Controller") || level >= LogLevel.Error)
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
                            return false;
                        },
                    });
            })
            .Build()
            .Run();
```

I've already added a registry key there for this app (since the app doesn't have admin rights and can't add a source) along with the EventMessageFile of `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\EventLogMessages.dll`. I've messed with different values of this including the non-64 framework folder and other v2 versions. There are no errors or warnings, and I can't find any logs that have anything related in them. I've also added a debug logger with `.AddDebug()` and it prints just fine the debug window.

I'm guessing it's something on the server side of things and not my code. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I can now re-create my app creating error logs in the eventlog. If I start my program by double-clicking the .exe, there is an authentication error that is thrown and gets sent to the log.

Comment: Seems that the issue resides on what user is the app executed with, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. I still had a "Logging" section of my appsettings.json that was set default to warning. Deleted that section and everything started printing!